# WCF service on root of IIS host

Tags: wcf, iis, service

How would I set up a WCF service hosted in IIS on the root of the domain?  i.e. http://www.example.com instead of http://www.example.com/Service1.svc/

I can't figure out how to get rid of the service filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Service1.svc to the default document names in IIS and move it to the top of the list.

Comment: Along with rewriting the path in the HttpContext.Current in an IHttpModule, that fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you really want?  If there is any slight chance that you might want a second service from the same domain someday, you'll wish that you hadn't exposed the root publicly that way.

Comment: I agree - this is certainly out of the norm.  Can you (nderraugh) maybe explain why you'd like to do this?

Comment: I was planning on having a single service and use UriTemplates to handle the path structure.

The service will be delivering an XHTML document.. essentially a web page.