# Host WCF request at root

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis-7

I have a WCF POX (RESTful) service which is working well.  It can be accessed at a Url which takes the format https://APPLICATIONNAME/service.svc/postdata

The APPLICATIONNAME is the host name and DNS name, to map the call through to IIS 7.

The question I have now, is that ideally I wouldn't want to use the "service.svc" part of the url and just use the following Url to post to the application;

https://APPLICATIONNAME/postdata

Any pointers on how I do this?  Ideally I wouldn't want to use aspnetcompatibility.  I would have thought this would be a standard thing to do - but can't fine on tips on how to do it.

Many thanks

Comment: You could prob work something out using the rewrite module in iis

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539978/wcf-service-on-root-of-iis-host